# UIRotationGestureRecognizer activates multiple times Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uigesturerecognizer

When using `UIRotationGestureRecognizer` the rotation is recognized but it triggers the action multiple times. Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let rotation = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.lol))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(rotation)
}

func lol() {
    print ("hi")
    UIView.animateWithDuration(5.0, animations: {
        let currTransform = self.view.transform
        let newTransform = CGAffineTransformConcat(currTransform, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI)))
        self.view.transform = newTransform

    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out UIRotationGestureRecognizer's state.

```
let rotation = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.lol(_:)))

func lol(sender: UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
    print(sender.state)
```

I expect you're just receiving `Began` and `End` states.

Answer (score 1):

UIRotationGestureRecognizer will trigger its assigned action as many times as it receives a notification that a rotational multi-finger touch gesture has been executed. It is expected that

```
lol()
```

will be called multiple times.

I'm assuming you want to rotate the view as the user uses a pinch gesture on the view object. In that case, instead of using UIView.animateWithDuration (in which you have to set a duration manually), you should listen for the **.rotation** property of the UIRotationGestureRecognizer instance, which will return the latest rotation value of the gesture recognizer, in radians.

You can then use this property to set the rotation of the view:

```
let transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.block.transform, rotation.rotation)
self.block.transform = transform
```

inside your lol() function.

Comment: I am not looking for a user interaction with the orientation. Rather, I am looking for the user to perform the gesture and the view rotates pi radians every time.